# Minimization of p-norm of diagonal

Tags: convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

As I am rather unfamiliar with optimization and convex programming my question might be a bit naive.

Let's start with a very simple semidefinite program
$$\min \, \, tr(X)$$
$$ s.t.\,  X \succeq 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \langle X, A_k\rangle = b_k, \quad k\in I$$
which is concerned with minimizing the trace over the intersection of an affine set with the cone of positive matrices.

If we replace $ tr(X)=\tau_1(X)$ by $\tau_\infty(X)$ (or any $\tau_p$ in between) where
$$
\tau_p(X) := \|(X_{i,i})_{i=1}^d\|_{\ell^p}
$$
the $p$-norm over the diagonal we loose linearity and the resulting problem does not qualify as a semidefinite program any more.

My question now is: What is the best way to solve the modified problem? Would one just use a general purpose solver or are there specialized methods for this type of problem?